# Matlab: Save matrix of function handles to a text file

Tags: file, matlab, cell-array, function-handle

For example my data is:

```
data = 

[1000] @(x)x.^2  @sin [0.5]
[2000] @(x)1./x  @cos [0.6]
```

I want to save `data` to a text file or another. (`data` is a `cell` matrix). How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can't you just save `data` in a `mat` file using [`save`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html)?

Comment: @natan I have tried sprintf, printf, save; but I didn't get what I desired. Function handles are making trouble.

Comment: @pm89 I tried. but gedit can not open the mat file. I tried to save as ascii, then the file is empty.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save data for later usage withing Matlab all you need is this

```
save('filename','variables separated by spaces'); % to save specific variables
save('filename'); % to save all variables
```

if you want to load the variables to the workspace again, use the following

```
load('filename');
```

if you need to write data as a readable text file instead of binary data, then try to use `fprintf`, almost usable the same way as C's `fprintf`. I advise you to check the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html)

Here's a little example :

```
name = 'John';
age = 20;
enter code here
file = fopen('yourfilename.txt','w') % w option stantds for 'write' permission
fprintf(file,'My name is %s and I am %d', name, age);
fclose(file); % close it when you finish writing all data
```

I didn't really understand how is your `data` matrix formatted. It doesn't seem to be correct matlab code.

Regards ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open it via `gedit` later you can use [`evalc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalc.html) to get the exact string you see in *command window* when you type `data`:

```
str = evalc('data');
```

Then write it to file using [`fopen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html) and [`fwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fwrite.html):

```
fid = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
fwrite(fid, str);
fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the string representation of an anonymous function use [char](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/char.html):

```
S = cell(size(data,1),1);
for iRow = 1:size(data,1)
    S{iRow}=sprintf('%d %s %s %d\n', ...
            data{iRow,1}, char(data{iRow,2}), char(data{iRow,3}), data{iRow,2}); 
end
```

and then write `S` to the output file.